# Ruby-Saml Certificate issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, saml

I am not sure if I am doing something wrong here but I've been stuck on this issue for quite some time. I am using the Ruby-saml gem (https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml) and I am not sure if my settings.certificate is valid. I used OpenSSL to generate the public/private key pair. Here is my public key:

```
$ cat cert.pem 
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

In Rails I tried multiple different way to get this to work:

```
      settings.certificate = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIE3zCCA8egAwIBAgIJANtTrhsq7mkmMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAMIGlMQswCQYD 
VQQGEwJVUzERMA8GA1UECBMITmV3IFlvcmsxDzANBgNVBAcTBkl0aGFjYTEbMBkG 
A1UEChMSQ29ybmVsbCBVbml2ZXJzaXR5MQ4wDAYDVQQLEwVEeXNvbjEjMCEGA1UE 
AxMaY3VtaW5vcnMuZHlzb24uY29ybmVsbC5lZHUxIDAeBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWEW5t 
YzUyQGNvcm5lbGwuZWR1MB4XDTE2MDQxMjE4MTUzOVoXDTI2MDQxMDE4MTUzOVow 
gaUxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMREwDwYDVQQIEwhOZXcgWW9yazEPMA0GA1UEBxMGSXRo 
YWNhMRswGQYDVQQKExJDb3JuZWxsIFVuaXZlcnNpdHkxDjAMBgNVBAsTBUR5c29u 
MSMwIQYDVQQDExpjdW1pbm9ycy5keXNvbi5jb3JuZWxsLmVkdTEgMB4GCSqGSIb3 
DQEJARYRbm1jNTJAY29ybmVsbC5lZHUwggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAw 
ggEKAoIBAQCnVjE8GIJe19Ba+361+c7ATDhBrzpGQoe+IDrDWw8B68HayaAvC8Pq 
WdNQNQ3SfHOdb+Vv0eywxHG7wRVVrJ+f8fLqmHBHfthzRG1JnGhReUXb/+wfkUEw 
DFZPEnEcj6rBcSbX5nsLVvupMXw43XB7ev/NX1SLsRU4trS25YMOozxjL+SfcKsW 
IQPgqD3usIArwS6b3UQ+ftuVfmWqKEqoUq25tUXoAporFkJyVqXZqe4g/Q+WqbX4 
cD9e1u7q8OlbSeVXUyPwRsNXzn1n+8tUbCc2k8+glEW5UJk7DY0AP95ry0ZcpfLr 
kgaOTqvbkUWCaZH1FP04SYG5Csw/8IDtAgMBAAGjggEOMIIBCjAdBgNVHQ4EFgQU 
q3ybbMNZOEXWgJ7/K0mSMx3VeTMwgdoGA1UdIwSB0jCBz4AUq3ybbMNZOEXWgJ7/ 
K0mSMx3VeTOhgaukgagwgaUxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMREwDwYDVQQIEwhOZXcgWW9y 
azEPMA0GA1UEBxMGSXRoYWNhMRswGQYDVQQKExJDb3JuZWxsIFVuaXZlcnNpdHkx 
DjAMBgNVBAsTBUR5c29uMSMwIQYDVQQDExpjdW1pbm9ycy5keXNvbi5jb3JuZWxs 
LmVkdTEgMB4GCSqGSIb3DQEJARYRbm1jNTJAY29ybmVsbC5lZHWCCQDbU64bKu5p 
JjAMBgNVHRMEBTADAQH/MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAA4IBAQBA8QEvcxLnjZURGb5/ 
a4JUVwU6noFdZpmI9FgBi7d3nKs+BNxL/1Het6Kk19T1kPlyDdG96asG6fbRH24G 
cJOoDvVpx6lxMu85gFpJVv/vtDmnlpiBoDH+v2I7O4ENhve76B7Z5XtT5FsjEdy4 
RAn1iczxq391vFNQJl0kCz2Khdv5CS3t6qNS42sPcRk9mjbnN0wz6jHxG5BfCVdk 
dXxoLuJVLzT7/sbBkT2SLkwQkPiYitb3LFoNFu+Sk8y+L4cVaeoA5XoEjmIbtkgD 
oLCrILf6t18C/R2AD0/huq2pFtxd/rng/yGMniTBc6aGDsv06RXo/5r7DsO0feXV 
cRzc
-----END CERTIFICATE-----"
```

I've also tried to just have Rails read the cert.pem file directly:

```
settings.certificate = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read("#{Rails.root}/cert.pem")).to_s
```

The issue is (which I am not sure is an issue), my key is a long inline string in the XML file (metadata for the SP)

```
<md:KeyDescriptor use="encryption">
<ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:X509Data>
<ds:X509Certificate>
MIIE3zCCA8egAwIBAgIJANtTrhsq7mkmMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAMIGlMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzERMA8GA1UECBMITmV3IFlvcmsxDzANBgNVBAcTBkl0aGFjYTEbMBkGA1UEChMSQ29ybmVsbCBVbml2ZXJzaXR5MQ4wDAYDVQQLEwVEeXNvbjEjMCEGA1UEAxMaY3VtaW5vcnMuZHlzb24uY29ybmVsbC5lZHUxIDAeBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWEW5tYzUyQGNvcm5lbGwuZWR1MB4XDTE2MDQxMjE4MTUzOVoXDTI2MDQxMDE4MTUzOVowgaUxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMREwDwYDVQQIEwhOZXcgWW9yazEPMA0GA1UEBxMGSXRoYWNhMRswGQYDVQQKExJDb3JuZWxsIFVuaXZlcnNpdHkxDjAMBgNVBAsTBUR5c29uMSMwIQYDVQQDExpjdW1pbm9ycy5keXNvbi5jb3JuZWxsLmVkdTEgMB4GCSqGSIb3DQEJARYRbm1jNTJAY29ybmVsbC5lZHUwggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQCnVjE8GIJe19Ba+361+c7ATDhBrzpGQoe+IDrDWw8B68HayaAvC8PqWdNQNQ3SfHOdb+Vv0eywxHG7wRVVrJ+f8fLqmHBHfthzRG1JnGhReUXb/+wfkUEwDFZPEnEcj6rBcSbX5nsLVvupMXw43XB7ev/NX1SLsRU4trS25YMOozxjL+SfcKsWIQPgqD3usIArwS6b3UQ+ftuVfmWqKEqoUq25tUXoAporFkJyVqXZqe4g/Q+WqbX4cD9e1u7q8OlbSeVXUyPwRsNXzn1n+8tUbCc2k8+glEW5UJk7DY0AP95ry0ZcpfLrkgaOTqvbkUWCaZH1FP04SYG5Csw/8IDtAgMBAAGjggEOMIIBCjAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUq3ybbMNZOEXWgJ7/K0mSMx3VeTMwgdoGA1UdIwSB0jCBz4AUq3ybbMNZOEXWgJ7/K0mSMx3VeTOhgaukgagwgaUxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMREwDwYDVQQIEwhOZXcgWW9yazEPMA0GA1UEBxMGSXRoYWNhMRswGQYDVQQKExJDb3JuZWxsIFVuaXZlcnNpdHkxDjAMBgNVBAsTBUR5c29uMSMwIQYDVQQDExpjdW1pbm9ycy5keXNvbi5jb3JuZWxsLmVkdTEgMB4GCSqGSIb3DQEJARYRbm1jNTJAY29ybmVsbC5lZHWCCQDbU64bKu5pJjAMBgNVHRMEBTADAQH/MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAA4IBAQBA8QEvcxLnjZURGb5/a4JUVwU6noFdZpmI9FgBi7d3nKs+BNxL/1Het6Kk19T1kPlyDdG96asG6fbRH24GcJOoDvVpx6lxMu85gFpJVv/vtDmnlpiBoDH+v2I7O4ENhve76B7Z5XtT5FsjEdy4RAn1iczxq391vFNQJl0kCz2Khdv5CS3t6qNS42sPcRk9mjbnN0wz6jHxG5BfCVdkdXxoLuJVLzT7/sbBkT2SLkwQkPiYitb3LFoNFu+Sk8y+L4cVaeoA5XoEjmIbtkgDoLCrILf6t18C/R2AD0/huq2pFtxd/rng/yGMniTBc6aGDsv06RXo/5r7DsO0feXVcRzc
</ds:X509Certificate>
</ds:X509Data>
</ds:KeyInfo>
</md:KeyDescriptor>
```

The IdP people said it was not valid when they tried to use it, he gave me an example of theirs and theirs was split across many lines unlike mine which is just a long string with no space:

```
https://shibidp.cit.cornell.edu/idp/shibboleth
```

Am I doing something wrong here? All I did was take the output from cat and pasted it to my SAML Settings.

Comment: The certificate need not be split in across multiple lines. Which error are you actually facing? Signature error?

Comment: Apparently it was fine all along, I guess I was just making work for myself... I was initially told there was an issue but after working with a different person they said it was fine

Answer (score 0):

looks like your X509 doesn't have any line breaks. That might be your problem.

Comment: This should not be a problem.